# PHP: date functions' results related to NEXT month are not correct (PHP bugs or sg. else?)

Tags: php, datetime, date, timestamp

I tried some date functions, because I would like to get some dates of the **next month** with PHP, but I experienced some problems.

The current date as a MySQL-compatible timestamp (`date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`) is the following:
`'2012-05-31 14:59:19'`

- `date('t', strtotime('next month'));` which gives the **number of days in the next month**, returns **31** as a result... which is not correct, because **June consists of only 30 days** (seems like it outputs the days of July).
- `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('next month'));`, which gives the **next month's timestamp format**, returns `'2012-07-01 14:59:19'`, but I would expect the following:
  `'2012-06-30 14:59:19'`.

So I tried some codes, here are my experiments, using [`date()`](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`DateTime class`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php): http://pastebin.com/3iaH4iSZ

And the OUTPUT looks like the following ([you can also see it here!](http://pastebin.com/tAM9zxrD)):
[image: PHP date functions related to NEXT month]

Are these PHP bugs, or do I misunderstand something?

---

I would expect the same results as when using MySQL's date functions, just a few examples:

```
SELECT NOW( )
```

2012-05-31 17:51:15

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

2012-06-30 17:51:15

```
SELECT DATE_ADD( '2013-01-30 17:51:15', INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
```

2013-02-28 17:51:15

```
SELECT DATE_ADD( '2013-01-31 17:51:15', INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
```

2013-02-28 17:51:15

Comment: Use [DateTime](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). It's more accurate.

Comment: Did you really read the whole question? :) Look at my code, you can see that I did use `DateTime`, and it didn't give the correct results either.

Comment: Follow @rasmus on twitter, he was talking about this very subject this morning - and read this http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#SEC125

Comment: @MarkBaker: thanks, that was useful, here's the tweet: http://twitter.com/rasmus/status/208157669452816384, and another important one: http://twitter.com/rasmus/status/208160760302538752. So, just to summarize: does PHP use GNU's date functions, so we should blame GNU date instead of blaming PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I found the solution, which behaves similar to MySQL's `DATE_ADD` function with `INTERNAL 1 MONTH`.
I tested my function with all the possibly problematic cases, and it seems to work correctly.
I paste it here, maybe someone will find it useful. I put some comments in this code, so I think it's clear enough.

The function is called `getOneMonthLaterTimestamp`. An example:

```
echo getOneMonthLaterTimestamp('2012-05-31 17:51:15');
```

Output: 2012-06-30 17:51:15

### The function

```
/**
 * Test function for dumping variables in a readable way
 * 
 * @param mixed $stuff
 * @param string $text
 * @return string 
 */
function my_var_export($stuff, $text = '...') {
    return '<p>' . $text . ' (' . gettype($stuff) . '):</p><pre>' . var_export($stuff, TRUE) . '</pre>';
}

/**
 * Get timestamp format of the date one month later 
 * than the date given in the argument/current date if left empty.
 * 
 * Behaves similar to MySQL's DATE_ADD function with INTERVAL 1 MONTH:
 * SELECT DATE_ADD('2012-05-31 17:51:15', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
 * --> 2012-06-30 17:51:15
 * SELECT DATE_ADD('2013-01-30 17:51:15', INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
 * --> 2013-02-28 17:51:15
 * 
 * these are equivalent to:
 * echo getOneMonthLaterTimestamp('2012-05-31 17:51:15');
 * echo getOneMonthLaterTimestamp('2013-01-30 17:51:15');
 * 
 * You can also call it without an argument. This way, the current date is taken as a basis.
 * echo getOneMonthLaterTimestamp();
 * 
 * @param string $DateTime_param date/time string
 * @see http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php
 * @see http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php
 * 
 * @return string Date one month later as a MySQL-compatible timestamp format
 */
function getOneMonthLaterTimestamp($DateTime_param = NULL) {
    // if argument is left empty, the current date is taken as a basis
    if (empty($DateTime_param)) {
        $DateTime_param = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    $lastDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime($DateTime_param);
    $lastDayOfNextMonth->modify('last day of next month');

    $nextMonth = new DateTime($DateTime_param);
    $nextMonth->modify('next month');

    if ($lastDayOfNextMonth->format('n') < $nextMonth->format('n')) {
        $oneMonthLaterTimestamp = $lastDayOfNextMonth->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
    else {
        $oneMonthLaterTimestamp = $nextMonth->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    return $oneMonthLaterTimestamp;
}
```

### Test cases

```
$timestamps_to_test_array = array(
  date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),   // 1. current date
  '2011-01-28 23:59:59', // 2.
  '2011-01-29 23:59:59', // 3.
  '2011-01-30 23:59:59', // 4.
  '2011-01-31 23:59:59', // 5.
  '2012-01-28 23:59:59', // 6.
  '2012-01-29 23:59:59', // 7.
  '2012-01-30 23:59:59', // 8.
  '2012-01-31 23:59:59', // 9.
  '2012-02-29 23:59:59', // 10.
  '2012-03-30 23:59:59', // 11.
  '2012-03-31 23:59:59', // 12.
  '2012-04-30 23:59:59', // 13.
  '2012-05-31 23:59:59', // 14.
  '2012-12-31 23:59:59', // 15.
  '2013-01-31 23:59:59', // 16.
  '2013-02-28 23:59:59', // 17.
);

$i = 1;

foreach ($timestamps_to_test_array as $timestamp_to_test) {
    $oneMonthLaterTimestamp = getOneMonthLaterTimestamp($timestamp_to_test);
    echo my_var_export($timestamp_to_test, '[' . $i . ']. Timestamp to test ($timestamp_to_test)');
    echo my_var_export($oneMonthLaterTimestamp, 'Timestamp + 1 month (getOneMonthLaterTimestamp($timestamp_to_test))');
    echo '<hr />';
    $i++;
}
```

### Output of the test cases

I pasted the output here: http://pastebin.com/rY5ZRBs9.
Here's a screenshot of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q23l.png

### Getting the number of days in the next month

```
/**
 * Get number of days in the next month
 *
 * @param string $DateTime_param date/time string
 * @return int Number of days in the next month
 */
function getNumberOfDaysInNextMonth($DateTime_param = NULL) {
    // if argument is empty, the current date is taken as a basis
    if (empty($DateTime_param)) {
        $DateTime_param = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    // DateTime instance
    $dateCurrent = new DateTime($DateTime_param);
    $dateCurrent->modify('last day of next month');
    return (int)$dateCurrent->format('t');
}

/**
 * It's identical to getNumberOfDaysInNextMonth()
 *
 * @see getNumberOfDaysInNextMonth
 */
function getLastDayOfNextMonth($DateTime_param = NULL) {
    return getNumberOfDaysInNextMonth($DateTime_param);
}
```

### Test case

```
$lastDayOfNextMonth = getLastDayOfNextMonth('2012-05-31 03:50:27');
echo my_var_export($lastDayOfNextMonth, "Get last day of next month (getLastDayOfNextMonth('2012-05-31 03:50:27'))");
```

**Output**:

```
Get last day of next month (getLastDayOfNextMonth('2012-05-31 03:50:27')) (integer):
30
```

Answer (score 1):

As of this:

> Get next month as a timestamp [ date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('next month')); ]:
> '2012-07-01 14:59:19'
>
> Get last day of the next month as a timestamp with DateTime class [ $dateObj->add(new >DateInterval('P1M')); $dateObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ]:
> '2012-07-01 14:59:19'

it is obvious that 'next month' outputs a date for JULY...

Try `strtotime('+1 month')` instead.

Edit: **Explanation:**
Today is the 31st of May. If You call `strtotime('next month')` it attempts to get the date for the 31st of June that is incorrect so it very right outputs the date for the 1st of July... Therefore I guess that also `strtotime('+1 month')` will fail...

**So better solution woul be to get the date of the 15th day of current month and use 'next month' or '+1 month' to that date...**

Comment: Don't think so... I guess it only adds +31 days and corrects the date to be a valid date... Same thing in February... If You think it is a bug then post it to a PHP bugtracker and You will see...

Comment: Quoting @rasmus on this very subject this morning: "It's the 31st of the month. Before filing a bug about relative dates in PHP, please read  http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#SEC125 "

Comment: @MarkBaker I read it. But maybe they could do some work instead of giving simple API to the underlying C functions. Like with strftime which uses different modifier on windows (%#d instead of %e): I think php should abstract this kind of quirks.

Comment: @shadyyx: OK, but I'm really surprised that on the 31st day of the actual month (if the 31st of the month is a valid date) the "next month" adds 31 days, which is the number of days in the actual month, and this messes up the whole calculation. So I don't think it's the "right" behaviour, as you mentioned. :) But thanks for your help! So, just to summarize: this way, should you inspect if the actual date is the 31st of the month, and if yes, you should add one day to this date, and calculate the end of that month instead, so you get the 30th of the month?

Comment: By the way, what if it's the 28th of February?

Comment: No, a better approach: what if it's the 30th OR 31st of January, 2013, and I want to get the next month? Btw., +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with some minor manipulation (i.e. if i'm getting your question right)

```
$next_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+1, 1, date("Y"));
//gets next month
echo "<br />".date("D jS M, Y", $next_month);
//sets the value
echo "<br />".date("t", $next_month);
//number of days next month
```

That should give you access to the months you want, because every month has a `first` day.
In other words, to get for the following year, you just change the appropriate value

Comment: OK, thanks, this is a good example to get the number of the next month's days, but what if I just want to simply add one month to the current date? So, how would I get `'2012-06-30 18:26:19'` when adding one month to the current date instead of getting `'2012-07-01 18:26:19'`? Btw., I upvoted your answer.